# Register folder on other drive ArcGIS 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I have ArcGIS for server 10.2.1. I've installed his on drive C but i wanna register folder on drive D.
[image]

ArcGIS Server Account have full premissions to drive D.

How can I register the folder on server?

Comment: Sometimes it's required to give permissions to the group and not just the account, then restart machine.

Comment: I added answer, glad it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced this myself once. It was required to give permissions to the group and not just the ArcGIS Server Account, then restart machine. Something that just did not go smooth in Windows settings.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same Error on our server.
What "group" are you refering to?
On our machine the User "arcgis" is not in any usergroup.